# Hide a specific checkbox with CSS

Tags: css, checkbox, hide

I have a number of checkboxes on a page and want to hide only ones attached to the advanced filter main class, I tried this and it doesnt work.

```
.advanced-filter:input[type='checkbox'] {
    display:none;
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to select an HTML element based on it's class and tag name(and attribute).
The correct syntax to do so is:

```
tagname.classname {
  properties;
}
```

So, you'd want to do something like:

```
input[type='checkbox'].advanced-filter {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of :input? I'm not aware of that as a pseudo-class.

what I think you want is:

```
input.advanced-filter[type='checkbox']
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither solutions worked, but I solved in the end by giving the checkbox an ID and hiding that ID.

Thanks for the help though, its always appreciated on this forum!